# Is there a way to force firebase to generate short temporary passwords?

Tags: firebase

When using FirebaseSimpleLogin's password reset function, the generated temporary password is 16 characters long. Is there any way to force this to a shorter length? Sixteen characters is a lot to type in to a mobile app...

https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/simplelogin/sendpasswordresetemail.html

Comment: [Engineer at Firebase] This feature does not yet exist, but we're always open to feedback. What password length would be *ideal*? Is there another way to represent the password that would suit your needs and make it shorter? Can you link directly to the mobile app so that the user doesn't have to type it in at all?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Rob. I would guess 6-8 characters would be a good compromise between security and hassle. Hard to say what would be ideal, so maybe it would be best to accept an optional password-length parameter... I am not sure how I would link directly back to the app since receiving the email is our proof that the user is who she says she is...